# httpd memory usage

Tags: memory, apache-httpd, out-of-memory

Having some problems with `httpd` (`Apache/2.2.29`) memory usage.

Over time, memory usage in the `httpd` processes creep up until it's eventually at 100%.

Last time I restarted `httpd` was about 24 hours ago. Output from `free -m` is:

```
[ec2-user@www ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1655       1415        239          0        202        424
-/+ buffers/cache:        788        866
Swap:         1023          4       1019
```

To prove that it's definitely `httpd`, I restarted `httpd` and ran `free -m` again:

```
[ec2-user@www ~]$ sudo service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
[ec2-user@www ~]$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          1655        760        894          0        202        360
-/+ buffers/cache:        197       1457
Swap:         1023          4       1019
```

So, restarting Apache takes free memory from 239 Mb to 894 Mb - which seems like a **big** leap.

I've been going through the list of currently enabled Apache modules (there's quite a lot) and disabled/removed `mod_wsgi` and `mod_perl` (neither of which are required for this server, which is running a PHP-based web application - Magento, specifically).

Based on https://servercheck.in/blog/3-small-tweaks-make-apache-fly, I've run `ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB";}'` and get the following output:

`[root@www ~]# ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024 " MB";}'
15.1328 MB
118.09 MB
127.449 MB
129.059 MB
117.734 MB
113.824 MB
125.062 MB
123.922 MB
119.855 MB
108.066 MB
136.23 MB
114.031 MB
113.27 MB
110.695 MB
102.113 MB
113.234 MB
186.816 MB
118.602 MB
0.835938 MB`

Running the other suggested diagnosis tool for `MaxClients` which is `ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024;}' | awk '{avg += ($1 - avg) / NR;} END {print avg " MB";}'` returns the following:

```
[root@www ~]# ps aux | grep 'httpd' | awk '{print $6/1024;}' | awk '{avg += ($1 - avg) / NR;} END {print avg " MB";}'
110.212 MB
```

This server (Amazon AWS `m1.small` instance) has `1.7 Gb` of RAM. So, therefore:

Any further pointers/suggestions on how best to tweak the `httpd` settings or how to diagnose what exactly might be causing this?

Comment: Note that to check memory usage by processes you need to look at the `-/+ buffers/cache` line; however in this case the change is comparable. Depending on how apache has been tuned, it may start with just a couple of processes ready for handling requests; after a period of many concurrent requests there will probably more processes forked to handle the load. The number of idle processes can also be tuned. So if apache grows to use too much memory, you need to do some tuning.

Comment: I'm OK at Apache server configuration but haven't done a huge amount in terms of performance tuning for Apache in the past. Any suggestions on which directives I should be looking at or guides? Is there a configuration setting I can enable to tell Apache to kill off forked processes after a certain amount of time? (It seems that Apache doesn't do this by default for some reason.)

Comment: This is the exact reason I've moved away from Apache... try Nginx or even Lighttpd.

Comment: Interesting. Heard good things about `nginx` so maybe it's time we give it a try, but honestly, I've been using Apache for years and never had any major problems. Magento really chews memory though.

Comment: Note that your script to calculate the average memory usage includes the low memory usage of the `grep httpd`-process (at least for me). To fix that i would recommend to exclude that line from the calculation like this: `ps aux | grep 'httpd' | grep -v grep | awk '{print $6/1024;}' | awk '{avg += ($1 - avg) / NR;} END {print avg " MB";}'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I've done to 'solve' it:

1. Set `MaxClients 7` (based on `(1740.8Mb Memory on server - 900Mb for MySQL + other stuff) / 111Mb average usage per httpd process = 7.5747747747747747747747747747748`)

Therefore:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients         7
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

2. Disable all Apache modules except for `authz_host_module`, `log_config_module`, `expires_module`, `deflate_module`, `setenvif_module`, `mime_module`, `autoindex_module`, `negotiation_module`, `dir_module`, `alias_module`, `rewrite_module`, `php5_module`
3. Remove the `mod_ssl` package since the client isn't using `https://` whatsoever.

I'll report back once this new configuration has been running a while  to see if this solves it.

Some inspiration here was borrowed from: http://www.activoinc.com/blog/2009/08/31/performance-optimized-httpd-conf-for-magento-ecommerce/ and http://www.activoinc.com/downloads/httpd.conf-magento

Comment: Above configuration has definitely helped massively.

Comment: Couple days later, 'memory leak' problems in `httpd` seem to be gone completely.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid option **MaxRequestsPerChild** helped in your case, as it's enables process recycling after defined number of requests, so memory leak is there, but not visible anymore.

Additionally: **MaxClients = ServerLimit * ThreadsPerChild**

In your case if you need only 7 concurrent users (MaxClients=7) it's totally enough with 2 process (just in case if one will fail to minimize downtime), so config can be:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       2
MinSpareServers    2
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit        2
MaxClients         8
ThreadsPerChild    4
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

I use **MaxClients 8**, just to make more equal request distribution between 2 processes.

Comment: In my case, I did not need this configuration if I wait a bit less than 24 hours, the memory will be freed with the default Apache configuration (checked with htop command after viewing analytics "Visits Over Time" for several years in Piwik / Matomo). But do you know where the memory leak could come from? Apache server or the PHP code running with mod_php? I guess it is better to fix the memory leak than trying to hide it with a specific configuration.

Answer (score 0):

## Memory computation

The other answers already tackle how to set the values. And for it you need to compute the memory usage of different elements of your system.

I want to tackle memory computation which can help many.

- `ps` show processes only and is a good tool to use if you want to use `RSS` as a value

  - `RSS` (Resident Set Size) over report memory, due to adding the whole shared memory (shared libraries) and repeatedly through all processes.
- `htop` or `top` by default show not only all processes but all threads of a given entity

  > To show process only press <kbd>H</kbd> to toggle between showing threads and not showing them

### Smem

For a better tool for computing memory usage, You can use `smem`

```
apt install smem
```

it will give `pss` value which it's better to rely on:

### Provided values

- RSS (Resident Set Size)

  - ram memory allocated to process
    Including shared memory (repetitive)
    shared libraries
    allocated once, used by many processes
    RSS over report memory usage
- PSS (Proportional Set Size)

  - divide the shared memory by percentage through all processes
  - 4 processes using same shared lib, they wil be computed with 25% each from the shared memory
  - in contrast to RSS, which for each process it compute 100% of that share memory
- USS (Unique Set Size)
- USS and PSS are terms and concepts that were proposed by Matt Mackall, the author of smem.

Some options

- k : memory in mb
- t: show total memory in the bottom

Filtering

- process
- mapping (libraries)
- user

### Getting apache2, mysql, php-fpm, nginx memory usage

Memory for apache2 process with total computation as well

```bash
smem -tk -P apache2
```

Same but only selecting pss column

```bash
smem -tk -c pss -P apache2
```

Showing pss total only

```bash
smem -tk -c pss -P apache2 | tail -n 1
```

Change `apache2` with any of the other processes.

Example

[image]

You can see each process with it's child processes consumption.

### PSS vs RSS

If we want to tune to the max of the server capabilities. PSS may be a better value to use.

Otherwise, we can use RSS as it over-reports memory. And that's can be safer. And then one can tune better under stress testing. Through experimentation.